# How to encode JSON Url in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to make a post to an API, and the link I'm using to make the post call has some URL parameters.

Link to make post: http://someservice/api/v1/requests?input_data=*encoded_data*

The parameter (input_data) is a JSON that needs to be encoded before.
When I use this [link](https://jsonformatter.org/json-url-encode) to encode the below JSON, and I add the encoded result to the URL and make the post with Postman, it works just fine.

```
{
   "request":{
      "requester":{
         "email_id":"**phx@phx.com**"
      },
      "subject":"**subject**",
      "description":"**description something**"
   }
}
```

This is what I have in my method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("projectRequest")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public IActionResult CreateConfig([FromForm] ConfigInputModel model) {
    try {
        var json =
            "{" +
                "\"request\":{ " + 
                "\"requester\":{ " + 
                    "\"email_id\" : \" " + model.Requester + " \" " +
                "}," +
                "\"subject\":\" " + model.Subject + " \" \", " +
                "\"description\":\" " + model.Description + " \" \" " +
                "}" +
            "}";

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        Encoding utf16le = new UnicodeEncoding(bigEndian: false, byteOrderMark: true,throwOnInvalidBytes: true);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
        
        var postResponse = httpClient.PostAsync("http://someservice/api/v1/requests?input_data=" +
                                     System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(json), content);
        
        return Ok(postResponse.Result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

My question is how can I encode the JSON variable, because I'm getting

> "Unable to parse the JSON"

response from the API. I suspect the escape characters in the JSON string I have are causing it, but can't figure it out for quite a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing JSON as a string, would suggest **setting the data as `object` with POCO `class` or `anonymous` type**. And next, serialize it to a JSON string.

**Benefit**: Avoid JSON syntax errors.

> anonymous type

```cs
var json = new {
    request = new {
        requester = new {
            email_id = model.Requester
        }
    },
    subject = model.Subject,
    description = model.Description
};
        
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rwMGag)

> Output

```
{"request":{"requester":{"email_id":"Requester"}},"subject":"Subject","description":"Description"}
```

Comment: Using an anonymous object is the best way to go I think. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code in my side and when I using `JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);` to transfer your json string, I got the error about `request.subject` and `request.description`,

[image]

then I found you made a mistake in this place, you should remove what I marked in the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: @Tine Wang, thanks for the catch. I had extra " chars. It's working fine now.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, and yes, it the most important thing that you solved it. And I also think it good to create an object and turn it into a json string. But I think it's not the answer about this question so I didn't mention that. HH